# what is the meaning of number of error block in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

In PLSQL block of statement, what is the meaning of number of error block in oracle like-

```
n_err_block := 100;
<block of statement....>

n_err_block := 200;
<block of statement....>

n_err_block := 300;
<block of statement....>
```

Comment: It is difficult to guess what might be going on, really. You should ask a person who wrote it. Therefore, my lucky guess: N_ERR_BLOCK looks like a (local) variable, and it gets those values (100, 200, 300). I presume that the author set them to easily debug code in case of errors. For example, if code fails and returns that procedure P_SOME_PROC failed and N_ERR_BLOCK = 200, you'd check code and navigate to N_ERR_BLOCK = 200 and see what's going on there. Logging purposes, shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice answer, kfinity, and I think it is worth highlighting what you added there: `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE`. This function (*and similar functionality from utl_call_stack in 12.1 and higher*) traces back to the line number on which the error was raised.

So if you ever see code that seems to be keeping track of how far you got in your program before an error was raised, scrap all of that and just make sure that `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE` is called when the error is logged.

Answer (score 3):

Without more code it's hard to say for sure. But that sort of thing is often used in debugging to figure out where the error happened in your code. In the EXCEPTION block, it probably prints `n_err_block` somewhere. This way, if it prints "n_err_block = 200", the developer knows that the error happened between `n_err_block := 200;` and `n_err_block := 300;`. Example:

```
declare
  n_err_block number;
begin
  n_err_block := 100;
  -- try something
  insert into table values (1, 2, 3);
  n_err_block := 200;
  -- try something else
  insert into table2 values (4, 5, 6);
  n_err_block := 300;
  update table3 set value2 = 7;
exception when others then
  dbms_output.print_line(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
  dbms_output.print_line('n_err_block = ' || n_err_block);
end;
/
```

Comment: But what is the meaning of Number of Error blocks. Till now i could not understand.

Comment: They are just a sequence of markers, there is no meaning. You can use any numbers you want; they should just not have any duplicates.